# How to know which tab is active in onCreateView function?

Tags: android

How can I know that which tab is active in my

> public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) function???

Following code is working for just fist navigation but after that in every tab it show last layout.

```
public final class RobozoxFragment extends Fragment {
private static final String KEY_CONTENT = "RobozoxFragment:Content";
private static int currentPosition = 100;
public static RobozoxFragment newInstance(String content,int position) {
    currentPosition = position;
    RobozoxFragment fragment = new RobozoxFragment();
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        builder.append(content).append(" ");
    }
    builder.deleteCharAt(builder.length() - 1);
    fragment.mContent = builder.toString();
    return fragment;
}
@Override

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View myFragmentView;

    if(currentPosition == 1){
        myFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.first, container, false);
    }else if(currentPosition == 2){
        myFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.second, container, false);
    }else if(currentPosition == 3){

        myFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.third, container, false);
    }else if(currentPosition == 4){
        myFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fourth, container, false);
    }else if(currentPosition ==5){
        myFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fifth, container, false);
    }else{
        myFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);
    }
    return myFragmentView;
}
```

I think problem is in `onCreateView` function where I am unable to get the active tab location.

How can i get this thing done.??

Comment: BTW: there is `switch/case` construct in Java. Become familiar with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the Solution :)
Get the Current Position By Using Bundle and Passing Arguments. Sample Code Below..

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView;
    Bundle args = getArguments();
    int currentView = args.getInt(Constants.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)-2;

    if(currentView == 0){
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lay1, container, false);
    }else if(currentView == 1){
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lay2, container, false);
    }else {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);
    }

    return rootView;
}


@Override
public Fragment getItem(int i) {
    switch (i) {
    case 0:
        // The first section of the app is the most interesting -- it offers
        // a launchpad into the other demonstrations in this example
        // application.
        return new LaunchpadSectionFragment();

    default:
        // The other sections of the app are dummy placeholders.
        Fragment fragment = new RobozoxSectionFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(Constants.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, i + 1);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }
}
```