# Populate android Listview on tab selected in fragments

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, tabs

I have added the default tabbed activity. I have one fragment with a listview (menuCardListView). I want to populate that listview with data (List) depending on the selected tab.I have implemented this inside the main activity:

```
public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction       fragmentTransaction) {
    // When the given tab is selected, switch to the corresponding page in
    // the ViewPager.
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

    try {

        ListView listView = (ListView)mViewPager.findViewById(R.id.menuCardListView);

        List<Product> groupList = new ProductController(mViewPager.getContext()).ProductList(1);

        MenuCardListViewAdapter adapter = new MenuCardListViewAdapter(this, groupList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

The listview is null? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying some code. I have found the answer to my problem. So I removed the code from onTabSelected to Oncreate view. Here I get the position of the tab from the args. This post helped me:

[How to know which tab is active in onCreateView function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13156662/how-to-know-which-tab-is-active-in-oncreateview-function)

Thanks.